# Subset data frame based on first letters of column name

Tags: r, subset

I have a large dataframe with multiple columns representing different variables that were measured for different individuals. The name of the columns always start with a number (e.g. 1:18). I would like to subset the df and create separete  dfs for each individual. Here it is an example:

```
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=10,ncol=18))
colnames(x) <- paste(1:18, 'col', sep="")
```

The column names of my real df is a composition of the Individual ID, the variable name, and the number of the measure (I took 3 measures of each variable). So for instance I have the measure b (body) for individual 1, then in the df I would have 3 columns named: 1b1, 1b2, 1b3. In the end I have 10 different regions (body, head, tail, tail base, dorsum, flank, venter, throat, forearm, leg). So for each individual I have 30 columns (10 regions x 3 measures per region). So I have multiple variables starting with the different numbers and I would like to subset then based on their unique numbers. I tried using grep:

```
partialName <- 1
df2<- x[,grep(partialName, colnames(x))]
colnames(x)
[1] "1col" "2col" "3col" "4col" "5col" "6col" "7col" "8col" "9col" "10col" 
"11col" "12col" "13col" "14col" "15col" "16col" "17col" "18col"
```

My problem here as you can see it doesn't separate the individuals because 1 and 10 are in the subset. In other words this selects everybody that starts with 1.
Ultimately what I would like to do is to loop over all my individuals (1:18), creating new dfs for each individual.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you provide the `colnames` and clarify what are you expecting?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Llopis. Ok. In the example above my colnames are:  [1] "1col"  "2col"  "3col"  "4col"  "5col"  "6col"  "7col"  "8col"  "9col"  "10col" "11col" "12col" "13col" "14col" "15col" "16col" "17col" "18col"

I would like to return diferent dfs subsetting the columns in which their names start with the same number. In the example above I would have 18 new dfs, each with 1 column, 1col, 2col, 3cols and so forth. Is that clear?

Comment: @user3293163 edit these into the question, not post as a comment.

Comment: If your column names were in the format 1_var1, 2_var1, 12_var10 then you could use `melt` to get the data in long format and then use `colsplit` to split the column names into 2 variables for the individual and the measure.  Subsequently you can `cast` the data and/or `split` it as required.

Comment: @user3293163 what do you *real* colnames look like, and do you have any control over them or are simply a given.

Answer (score 1):

I think keeping the data in one `data.frame` is the best option here. Either that, or put it into a list of `data.frame`'s. This makes it easy to extract summary statistics per individual much easier.

First create some example data:

```
df = as.data.frame(matrix(runif(50 * 100), 100, 50), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names_variables = c('spam', 'ham', 'shrub')
individuals = 1:100
column_names = paste(sample(individuals, 50), 
                     sample(names_variables, 50, TRUE), 
                     sep = '')
colnames(df) = column_names
```

What I would do first is use `melt` to cast the data from wide format to long format. This essentially stacks all the columns in one big vector, and adds an extra column telling which column it came from:

```
library(reshape2)
df_melt = melt(df)
head(df_melt)
  variable      value
1    85ham 0.83619111
2    85ham 0.08503596
3    85ham 0.54599402
4    85ham 0.42579376
5    85ham 0.68702319
6    85ham 0.88642715
```

Then we need to separate the ID number from the variable. The assumption here is that the numeric part of the variable is the individual ID, and the text is the variable name:

```
library(dplyr)
df_melt = mutate(df_melt, individual_ID = gsub('[A-Za-z]', '', variable),
                          var_name = gsub('[0-9]', '', variable))
```

essentially removing the part of the string not needed. Now we can do nice things like:

```
mean_per_indivdual_per_var = summarise(group_by(df_melt, individual_ID, var_name), 
                                       mean(value))
head(mean_per_indivdual_per_var)
  individual_ID var_name mean(value)
1            63     spam   0.4840511
2            46      ham   0.4979884
3            20    shrub   0.5094550
4            90      ham   0.5550148
5            30    shrub   0.4233039
6            21      ham   0.4764298
```

Comment: Dear Paul Hiemstra, this looks really good but I am still having a little trouble. First, I need to get my data back into the original format (each variable in a different column). Second, for each variable I have three different measures, for example 63spam1, 63spam2, 63spam3. And this interfere with the generation of individual_ID, since 63spam1 becomes 631. Any idea how to deal with this? Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Please extend your question with the additional details, and show us what you tried in solving the issue (e.g. using my example code). If you get stuck coming up with your own solution, either edit this question or ask a new one.

Comment: Thanks @Paul Hiemstra.  I changed your code accordingly. Now the column names have a similar structure to my original data. They start with a number (Individual ID), then the variable name (region where the variable was measured), and then another number (repetition). For example in your code above you have the column 81shrub1 (individual 81, region shrub, measure1). What I want in the end is one df for each Individual ID.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `colnames` are the standard ones of a data.frame, so to get just the column 1 you can do this:

```
df2 <- df[,1] #Where 1 can be changed to the number of column you wish.
```

There is no need to subset by a partial name.
Although it is not recommended you could create a loop to do so:

```
for (i in ncol(x)){
  assing(paste("df",i), x[,i]) #I use paste to get a different name for each column
}
```

Although the @paulhiemstra solution avoids the loop.

So with the new information then you can do as you wanted with grep, but specifically telling how many matches you expect:

```
df2<- x[,grep("1{30}", colnames(x))]
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I used a bad example of variable names to illustrate my problem. In my case I can't work if the column numbers.

Comment: Then, what are your real column names? If you say you have three observation of each variable (I assume that this mean each column you can create nested dataframes: The data frame that contains all the data, and several dataframes inside for each variable. But please try to complete your question, we can not guess all this issues.

Comment: The column names of my real df is a composition of the Individual ID, the variable name, and the number of the measure (I took 3 measures of each variable). So for instance I have the measure b (body) for individual 1, then in the df I would have 3 columns named: 1b1, 1b2, 1b3. In the end I have 10 different regions (body, head, tail, tail base, dorsum, flank, venter, throat, forearm, leg). So for each individual I have 30 columns (10 regions x 3 measures per region).

Comment: Please add a reproducible example that accurately reflects your situation. The lack of detail in your question leads to the lack of detail in the answers.